# React Native: Invalid hook call

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make android application with react native.After creating project and install all dependencies i want to use use Hook inside navigator like this:

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Dashboard: DashboardScreen,
    ListSurveyor: {
        screen: topSurvayorsNavigator,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            const dispatch = useDispatch();
            const [term, setTerm] = useState('');

            const searchServeyor = (item) => {
                console.log('nav: ', item);
                dispatch(survayouActions.searchSurveyouList(item))
            }
            switch (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routeName"]) {
                case "ActiveSurveyor":
                    return {
                        header: () => <CustomHeader
                            title='Active'
                            // term={term}
                            // onTermChange={setTerm}
                            onTermSubmit={searchServeyor}
                        />
                    }

                case "DeActiveSurveyor":
                    return {
                        header: () => <CustomHeader
                            title='DisActive'
                            onTermSubmit={searchServeyor}
                        />
                    }
                default:
                    return { title: (navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["routes"])[(navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]["index"])].routeName }
            }
        }
    },
    Audited: AuditedFileNumSurveyor,
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultNavOptions
});
```

I imported useState and useDispatch like below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
```

But When i run application i got this error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I used hook inside method `navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {` but what is happen?

This is package.json information:

```
{
  "name": "RNMngm",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.5.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.4",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.5",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.7.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.7.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hooks can only be used in a component, and cannot be used in navigator or navigationOptions. If u need to use state in navigator or navigationOptions, u need to setParams in the component and then use the getParam method in navigationOptions

Comment: with your explanations how could i invoke `searchServeyor` from my custom view? i am beginner in react native. This is custom header code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DykmZ8Ghzh/   @HowardWu

Comment: The green box http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=a22b294fbb1c70673c4a9d043d0298b3 is custom header .I want to when pressed enter down list be filtered  @HowardWu

Comment: Move the hooks codes and searchServeyor function into component. You need to manage states in component only. In the component, before rendering, add useEffect(props.navigation. setParams({searchServeyor: searchServeyor}), []) and in the navigationOptions, replace searchServeyor with navigation.getParam(‘searchServeyor’)